# Function in python that will return a list of only truncated integers

Tags: python

So I am working on code in a class, and I have a problem where my teacher wants me to: *"Write a Python function that will take a list of numbers as a parameter(list can be a mixed list), and returns a new list comprised of the integer values(truncated in the case of a float), of the original list. E.g. the list [5, 6.4, 7.5, 8.8, 2, 2.1] returns [5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 2]"*

I've started the funtion already, but I am stuck on the part of deceifering whether or not a value in the list is an int or float... This is what I have:

```
   def int_list(a_list):
       for x in a_list:
           if x = int:
```

I don't think we can ask if x is an int or float without saying type(x), but I dont think my teacher wants us using any Python built in library functions.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Don't "decide"; just truncate the number.  Use the `int` method.

Comment: You can use 1) Math.floor function  or 2) Convert it to string then look for dot or period.  Can you use any python functions I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if isinstance(x, float):
   x = int(x)
```

OR, if you want to avoid the use of a library function, you can do:

```
if x % 1 != 0:
    x = int(x)
```

For example: try executing `print(5.5%1)` and `print(5%1)`.

OR, you can just simply use `x = int(x)` if it is guaranteed that the values will be numbers. Otherwise, you can use try, catch to handle exceptions.

Comment: I'm not sure if my teacher wants us to use built in library functions like isinstance() though. How would I rewrite that if statement not using the isinstance() part?

Comment: sorry, I noticed it later. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work, turns out all I had to do was simply x = int(x) instead of an if statement there.

Comment: What is the use of if x % 1 != 0:?  It is useless.

Comment: @anonyXmous true, but the only part I really needed was x = int(x)

Comment: @anonyXmous `x % 1` will be nonzero for most floats (but let values like 1.0 through)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a function. Use a list comprehension instead:

```
>>> list = [5, 6.4, 7.5, 8.8, 2, 2.1]
>>> nl = [int(x) for x in list]
>>> nl
[5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 2]
```

You can think of the list comprehension as a function that gets applied to all of its elements:

```
>>> def process_list(a_list, a_func):
...     new_list = []
...     for x in a_list:
...        new_list.append(a_func(x))
...     return new_list
... 
>>> process_list(list,int)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 2]
```

but as you see, a list comprehension does a lot of this stuff on its own, and you only have to supply a function that translates each value to a new one.

(And technically speaking, you don't even *have* to process the original values. The list will be iterated for each of its elements and the function will be called for each, but what the function actually does with it is none of Python's concern.)

Comment: I know I could have done this, but my teacher specifically wanted a function that took a list as a parameter. I put the exact problem in my post... turns out all I had to do was `def list_to_int(a_list):
    int_list = []
    for x in a_list:
        number = int(x)
        int_list.append(number)
    return int_list` Ignore that ugly formatting, idk how to post raw code in a comment...

Comment: @LukeH: ... that was my first `process_list`, but I rejected it because it seemed "too obvious". Next time, if you already know you could use a list comprehension but are "not allowed to", please mention it.

Comment: My bad, still new to this site. I stated in the post I have to write it within a function but I should've gave more info I suppose. Thanks anyway for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_list = [5, 6.4, 7.5, 8.8, 2, 2.1]

def iterate_list(sample_list):

       new_list = []
       for num in sample_list:
               num = int(num)
               new_list.append(num)

        return new_list



print(iterate_list(sample_list))
```

your output will be:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 2]
```

1. We have a sample_list of the numbers you mentioned for the list.
2. We create a function to iterate over each item in the list, and we create a parameter called (sample_list). The arg that we pass when we call the function will be the sample_list that we created.
3. We create an empty list called new list to store the integer version of each value in the sample_list.
4. We run a for loop that will iterate over each number in the sample_list, and we will create a variable called num that will store the integer value of that particular number. We will then append that integer value to the new_list, and then return the new list.
5. We then call the function. In this case I print the output to make sure that I got the proper output, but you do not have to print when you call the function.